# Multiple links on a webpage pointing to the same URL

Tags: seo, links, pagerank

Does having multiple links on a webpage pointing to same internal URL impact your PR negatively? Would it look spammy or will the repeated links just be ignored?

Comment: Webpage you think about is internal webpage or external?

Comment: From my experience all links will get counted as one, but anchor variations might count.

Comment: @Zistoloen - Internal as i have mentioned in my question - "internal URL"!

Comment: @Vikas Gulati - I mentioned webpage where your links come from.

Comment: @Vikas Gulati - When I say on a **webpage** pointing to same **internal URL** isn't it obvious that the **webpage** in context is internal!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Cutts, Google's head spam fighter, [answered this question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYWlEItizjI) in a YouTube video a while back. In short:

- it's been tweaked somewhat, but at least in the original formulation of Pagerank, multiple links from page A to page B would each flow PR
- it's probably not worth the effort to try to sculpt your PR to this level.

Lots of reputable websites have multiple links like this, for example repeating links in the header and the footer. I wouldn't worry about looking spammy unless it starts to get excessive or degrade the user experience.

Comment: thanks a lot. even i found the video after posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

If these external links to the same internal URL are naturals, there is no problem. Otherwise, if you created these links for SEO, Google can consider them as non-naturals. In this last case, Google can impact negatively your PR because it looks like spammy.